# VS2015 compiler Generates 64 bit *obj files in my 32 bit Intermed dir instead of the configured 64 bit one

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So, I have a problem with object files being generated in the wrong folder in `.\Release` (32 bit build folder) for my x64 bit configs and when I select 32 but for builds they fail as they try to read the objects. The issue is I cant find where to reconfigure the directory to write the object files to for the 64 bit platform builds to fix this issue. Also present on the 64 bit debug builds where they write their object files to the 32 bit debug folder while being built.

So, Where Can I and how can I change this?

ok so, I just tested to verify I set it to Release x64 config to build the solution in after deleting the folders that has all the build files in them and it confirms the obj files are written in the 32 bit Release and Debug folders after I copied their settigns but for the 64 bit platform. I thought this would change their intermed dir to x64 like on the settings for that plarform so it means the compiler must be missreading the 32 bit platform settings for it or something.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the question?

Comment: I am saying the IDE thinks to generate the Object files *obj in the 32 bit build folder for debug and release. The Question is ``Where can I find something to change this and how can I change this?`` This is because I need to change this so this does not conflict with my other builds of this thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful that describes either the problem you're having or question you're asking. *I have an object generation issue* has absolutely no relevant information in it. Your title should make it clear what you're asking in a way that will be useful to future readers who see it in a search result. Your question *seems* to be about where the compiler generates 64-bit **object (.obj)  files*, but it's really unclear if that's what you actually mean. You might want to re-state the issue while you're editing the title.

Comment: done got it edited.

Answer (score 0):

The directory settings are on the first page of the Project Properties. You should probably just set the directories to different values.

For me it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out that the Settings on the IDE was fine but the only way to change it was to overwrite some settings to the 64 bit platform within Notepad++ as the settings that was not set right was not possible to change from within the IDE itself.